# Has Stripe API for downloads Receipt?

Tags: stripe-payments

In Stripe Payment System, for download Invoice.pdf we can retrieve `Invoice` object by its id via Stripe API and then examine field `Invoice.invoice_pdf`
See https://stripe.com/docs/api/invoices/object#invoice_object-invoice_pdf

Is there a similar way to get Receipt?

On Stripe Dashboard both are available. See
[image]

Answer (score 10):

Hope i'm not too late for this...
You can just add a /pdf subroute to receipt_url (do note there's a query in receipt_url)

eg: https://pay.stripe.com/receipts/invoices/.../pdf?s=ap

Struggled with this the entire day just to make this discovery :D

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This works indeed!

Comment: Doesn't work...

Answer (score 6):

You can get the `receipt_url` from charges using the charge_id that you can get from an `invoice object's` `charge` property.

This is not a link to the PDF, but on the page that is linked, there is a pdf to download, so you could parse this page and extract the PDF.

See about the `charge object`:

https://stripe.com/docs/api/charges

And how to retrieve the charge, with the example:

https://stripe.com/docs/api/charges/retrieve

Comment: I asked for Receipt, how to get Invoice I pointed in my question

Comment: I apologize for overlooking this. I have edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have answered this in another stackoverflow answer here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/68059986 using Java where it uses the charge API, downloads the receipt HTML page (using `receipt_url`), extracts the receipt PDF download link and saves it to disk.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, simply adding `/pdf` in the end of receipt url as mentioned in other answers, does not work as expected, only in some cases.

Here is what works for me:

1. `invoice.charge.receipt_url`
2. `checkout.session.invoice.charge.receipt_url`

Adding `/pdf` to the `receipt_url`s found above works. There was one scenario in which adding `/pdf` resulted in error.